# JavaFx рисование на ImageView и его подводные камни

Tags: java, javafx

У меня есть картинка загружаемая в imageView, я видел примеры что можно рисовать даже на нем, но возможно ли сохранить картинку вместе с изменениями? шерстил интернет, но конкретного ответа не нашел.

Comment: ImageData, с ним колдуйте

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, сохранить картинку возможно. Вот простой пример, который демонстрирует данное поведение.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.RenderedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class TestApplication extends Application
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage)
    {
        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView();

        Group group = new Group();

        Image image = new Image("pathToImage");
        imageView.setImage(image);

        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(40, 40, 300, 300);
        rectangle.setFill(Color.RED);

        group.getChildren().add(imageView);
        group.getChildren().add(rectangle);
        pane.setCenter(group);

        Button button = new Button("Save image");
        button.setOnAction(e ->
        {
            try
            {
                WritableImage snapshot = group.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), null);
                File file = new File("test.png");
                RenderedImage renderedImage = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(snapshot, null);
                ImageIO.write(renderedImage, "png", file);
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        pane.setTop(button);
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 400, 400);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

В данном примере нет логики для рисования, но тут показано, что мы на картинку наложили красный прямоугольник и сохранили полученное в файл. Основная логика в том, что вам необходимо создать `Group`, в которой будет лежать `ImageView` и все остальные нарисованные компоненты ( Rectangle в приведенном выше примере). Далее вы для этой `Group` создаете `WritableImage` и сохраняете его в файл.